# Pandas Modify Dataset to Have Equal Values from both Classifications

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, machine-learning, dataframe

I have a Dataset with true and false values for as classifiers. I have a DataFrame representation of this Dataset. However this dataset has about a ratio of 30 : 70 of true and false values for the classifier. I would ideally want 50 : 50 for both classifiers. What is the best way to show how many True and False Values I have of both classifications and then drop some rows of data from the classification with the highest number?

Eg DF :

```
    Language    Trustworthy
           en   0
           du   0
           li   0
           tm   0
           en   1
           en   0
           en   0
           en   1
           fr   0
           en   1
```

I would ideally want to drop 4 of the above dataset which has trustworthy value of 0. This is just a very small subset of my Dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group values in column and than see how many elements is in groups.

```
data = '''Language    Trustworthy
           en   0
           du   0
           li   0
           tm   0
           en   1
           en   0
           en   0
           en   1
           fr   0
           en   1'''

import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv( StringIO(data), index_col=None, sep='\s+')

#--------------------------------------------------------------------

print df.groupby('Trustworthy').size()

'''
Trustworthy
0              7
1              3
dtype: int64
'''
```

or

```
for name, group in df.groupby('Trustworthy'):
    print "name:", name, "| len:", len(group)

'''
name: 0 | len: 7
name: 1 | len: 3
'''
```

---

To drop last 4 rows with 0

```
df = df.drop( df[ df['Trustworthy'] == 0 ].tail(4).index )

print df
```

result

```
  Language  Trustworthy
0       en            0
1       du            0
2       li            0
4       en            1
7       en            1
9       en            1
```

Comment: Thank You. The grouping worked however when I drop data from tail I don't have 4 data points dropped. For instance in a sample dataset Ive got 93 false and 323 true. When i drop 1,2,3 or any number from tail i end up with 29 false and 187 true. I am not sure whats going on here?

Comment: I thing problem is what is your index. If you use column `Language` as index than `tail(1).index` can give you for example `en` and then all rows with `en` will be droped. I have unique indexes `0,1,2,...9` so I have no problem with that. Print `df.index` to see your indexes. Use `d.reset_index(inplace=True)` to stop using `Language` as index.

Comment: BTW `read_csv` use automaticly first column as index, so I use `index_col=None` to stop that bahavior.